# How to put division elements side by side?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4

I want to have the text "burger king" written just to the right of the logo, can someone tell how to do that? I tried to do it by using bootstrap class pull-left but no change appeared.

This is what my page looks like:

[image: this is what my page looks]

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: gold;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 40px;
}

.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DEV RESTAURANT</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restaurant.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a class="pull-left" href="restaurant.html">
            <img id="logo-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg/640px-Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg.png" alt="burger king" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="restaurant.html">
            <h1>Burger King</h1>
          </a>
        </div>

      </div>
    </nav>>

  </header>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I would probably leverage Bootstrap's built-in [flexbox classes](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.5/utilities/flex/):

```
<div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-start">
```

```css
body {
  font-size: 16px;
  background-color: #61122f;
  font-family: 'Oxygen', sans-serif;
}

#header-nav {
  background-color: gold;
}

#logo-img {
  width: 150px;
  height: 150px;
  margin: 10px 15px 10px 40px;
}

.float-container {
  border: 3px solid #fff;
  padding: 20px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DEV RESTAURANT</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restaurant.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light ">
      <div class="container-fluid d-flex justify-content-start">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="restaurant.html">
            <img id="logo-img" src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg/640px-Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg.png" alt="burger king" class="d-inline-block align-text-top">
          </a>
        </div>

        <div class="navbar-brand">
          <a href="restaurant.html">
            <h1>Burger King</h1>
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score -1):

Bootstrap‘s grid system (https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/) might help in this case; you can place div elements side-by-side using this code snippet:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm">
      One of three columns
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

To correctly align the elements, you can use Bootstrap‘s `align-items-center` class.

Source: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/layout/grid/ and [TutorialRepublic](https://www.tutorialrepublic.com/faq/how-to-vertical-align-a-div-in-bootstrap.php)

Answer (score -2):

```html
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
  <title>DEV RESTAURANT</title>
  <!-- Required meta tags -->
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">

  <!-- Bootstrap CSS -->
  <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.1.0/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-KyZXEAg3QhqLMpG8r+8fhAXLRk2vvoC2f3B09zVXn8CA5QIVfZOJ3BCsw2P0p/We" crossorigin="anonymous">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="restaurant.css">
</head>

<body>
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-light ">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <a href="restaurant.html">
            <img src="https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/thumb/8/85/Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg/640px-Burger_King_logo_%281999%29.svg.png" alt="burger king" height="75" width="75"> Burger King:
          </a>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <!-- Optional JavaScript -->
  <!-- jQuery first, then Popper.js, then Bootstrap JS -->
  <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js" integrity="sha384-q8i/X+965DzO0rT7abK41JStQIAqVgRVzpbzo5smXKp4YfRvH+8abtTE1Pi6jizo" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.7/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-UO2eT0CpHqdSJQ6hJty5KVphtPhzWj9WO1clHTMGa3JDZwrnQq4sF86dIHNDz0W1" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
  <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JjSmVgyd0p3pXB1rRibZUAYoIIy6OrQ6VrjIEaFf/nJGzIxFDsf4x0xIM+B07jRM" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Code without explanation is rarely helpful. See [answer].